# MYSQL Error 1052 issue - Unsure why this is wrong

Tags: mysql

I have read about this issue and I believe I have written this correctly, however I am still receiving the 1052 error message stating that column "form_name" in field list is ambiguous...

I have two tables `form_status` and `F1`

```
SELECT form_status.custom_id, F1.custom_id, form_name, uid 
FROM form_status 
JOIN F1 ON F1.custom_id=form_status.custom_id;
```

Any help would be appreciated...

Thanks!

**EDIT:**  I believe I have figured it out...I need to append the table name to ALL of the selected columns...however, when I read a few of other posts about this issue, I did not see this...

This is what I had changed:

```
SELECT form_status.custom_id, F1.custom_id, F1.form_name, F1.uid 
FROM form_status 
JOIN F1 ON F1.custom_id=form_status.custom_id;
```

**EDIT 2:** I see! because form_status appears in both tables you need to tell mysql what table to grab the data from. Thanks a lot for the help guys! I appreciate it

Comment: That means you have `form_name` filed in 2 tables, `form_status`, and `F1`. The engine doesn't know which one you refer in `SELECT`...

Comment: We cannot say much without you posting the table structure. But most likely you should use `F1.form_name`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the table name in front of `form_name`: i.e., `form_status.form_name` or `F1.form_name`.

This is because you have column `form_name` in both tables, so without the table name it's impossible to pick the right one.

Comment: wow, ok that makes alot of sense! Thanks! I will mark this as the answer when it lets me! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

`form_name` fields exist in both `F1` and `form_status` tables. Clarify what `form_name` you are selecting:

```
form_status.form_name
```

OR

```
F1.form_name
```

Comment: Yeah, @musical_coder and you made this make sense! Thanks for the help